# assigning values to select option with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select option with name `inv_type_+(count)`.I have to add values by `jquery`.

I used

```
 $("inv_type_"+count).val();
```

But that does not work.How to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are missing the class or id selector:

```
$(".inv_type_"+count).val("select");
```

Or from your paragraph I'm feeling it should be name:

```
$("[name='inv_type_"+count+"']").val("select");
```

Comment: @user3789344 if this works. Please mark as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*I have a select option with name inv_type_+(count).*

You need to use **[attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**:

```
$("[name='inv_type_"+count+"']").val("select");
```